# Why does node http client keeps running if response is not read?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have just got started with Node.js and I am trying to write a simple http client that just sends a post request to a server.

```
var req = http.request(
        {
                host : 'localhost',
                port: 3000,
                url : '/',
                method:'POST'

        },function(res){
                console.log('res status - ' + res.statusCode);
                res.on('data', function(){}); //<--------

        }
);
```

(I have omitted the code that writes to request and calls req.end()). I have observed if the last line is commented out  and the client doesn't read the response, the client doesn't terminate. What is the reason behind this ?

Comment: You have to call `req.end()`, `req.send()` or something similar to terminate and send something back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is because of following [Node](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) implementation:
Issuing `http.request()` creates an object `http.ClientRequest` with below behaviour

> If no '**response**' handler(i.e 2nd argument of request method) is added, then the response will be entirely discarded. However, if you add a 'response' event handler, then you must consume the data from the response object, either by calling **response.read()** whenever there is a 'readable' event, or by adding a '**data**' handler, or by calling the .**resume()** method. Until the data is consumed, the '**end**' event will not fire. Also, until the data is read it will consume memory that can eventually lead to a 'process out of memory' error.

Comment: I think the line "I have observed that if the client doesn't read the response by calling the last line, the client doesn't terminate" in OP implies that he want to understand why client doesn't terminate when he commented out 'data' handler